# ¿Por qué da error sobreescribir un class field de método en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, clase

Tengo una clase Animal que tiene una subclase Deer(ciervo). Si agrego un método de forma normal en Animal y lo sobreescribo en la subclase Deer no hay problema. La cosa es que al usar class field de método en Animal para declarar la función(mi intención con esto es evitar la pérdida del this al pasar el método como callback, por ejemplo en setTimeout(deer1.doSomething, 1000)) me genera un error en consola y no ejecuta el método.

Declarando el método normalmente:

```js
class Animal {
    constructor(name) {
        this.speed = 0;
        this.name = name;
    }
    run(speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
        console.log(`${this.name} corre a una velocidad de ${this.speed}.`);
    }
    
    //Si declaro stop directamente como método, no hay problema
    stop() {
        this.speed = 0;
        console.log(`${this.name} se queda quieto.`);
    }
}

let animal = new Animal("Mi animal");

class Deer extends Animal {

    constructor(name, tailLength) {
        super(name);
        this.tailLength = tailLength;
    }

    hide = () => {
        console.log(`${this.name} se ha escondido!`);
    };

    stop = () => {
        super.stop();
        this.hide();
    };
};

let ciervo = new Deer('Ciervo Rojizo', 7);

animal.stop()

ciervo.stop();
```

Declarando el método dentro de class field:

```js
class Animal {
        constructor(name) {
            this.speed = 0;
            this.name = name;
        }
        run(speed) {
            this.speed = speed;
            console.log(`${this.name} corre a una velocidad de ${this.speed}.`);
        }
        
        //Al declarar stop como class field, genera un error al llevarlo a la subclase
        stop = () => {
            this.speed = 0;
            console.log(`${this.name} se queda quieto. Estamos en la clase padre`);
        }
    }

    let animal = new Animal("Mi animal");

    class Deer extends Animal {

        constructor(name, tailLength) {
            super(name);
            this.tailLength = tailLength;
        }

        hide = () => {
            console.log(`${this.name} se ha escondido!`);
        };

        stop = () => {
            super.stop; //Esto ya no da error, pero no ejecuta el método de la clase padre
            this.hide();
        };
    };

    let ciervo = new Deer('Ciervo Rojizo', 7);
    
    animal.stop();

    ciervo.stop();
```

Comment: ¿Puedes aclarar tu pregunta? ¿Qué significa "class field de método"?

Comment: @Orici class field es cuando declara una propiedad directamente dentro de la clase, sin usar constructor o el this antes de la propiedad. En este artículo https://es.javascript.info/class#vinculacion-de-metodos-binding-usando-campos-de-clase explican un poco las ventajas de usar un método dentro de un class field

Comment: Es que en ese caso, el campo `stop` de la clase padre tiene que ser llamado así desde la clase hija: **`super.stop; //Esto NO da error`** pues has declarado `stop` como una propiedad o campo de la clase, no como un método.

Comment: @A.Cedano Ya lo he intentado pero al hacerlo así no llama al método, literalmente no hace nada, como si fuera una propiedad y no un método

Comment: Edita el snippet y pon cómo lo has modificado, En mi caso funciona.

Comment: @A.Cedano Ok, lo acabo de editar. Se ve que aunque no hay error. no ejecuta el super.stop(o sea el stop de la clase padre) y solo ejecuta this.hide()

Comment: Me he permitido editar el segundo bloque de código, poniendo el mensaje así: `Mi animal se queda quieto. Estamos en la clase padre`, y ese contenido sí se muestra en la consola, por tanto, el `stop` de la clase padre se está llamando.

Comment: @A.Cedano Sí se ejecuta porque lo estás llamando directamente desde la clase padre. La cosa es que al llamarlo desde dentro del stop de la clase hijo (super.stop()) no funciona, y solamente ejecuta el hide()

Comment: No, se llama desde esta clase: `class Deer extends Animal` que es la clase hija ¿no?